# Data truncated in CSV output from SQL*Plus

Tags: sqlplus

My simple requirement is to output the result of .sql file in a .csv file and I am getting the results also but some columns data is getting truncated. I have tried many settings but unable to figure it out. Below are the settings I am using inside .sql file:

```
set head off echo off term off feedback off wrap off
set line size 500
set pages 0
set long 500
column Result format a500
spool ScoreCardResults.csv
SELECT 'SCORECARD_IDENTIFIER'||','||'SCORECARD_NAME'||','||'SC_DESC'||','||'SCORE_NAME'||','||'TOTAL_ROWS'||','||'INVALID_ROWS'||','||'SCORE'||','||
'METRIC_WEIGHT'||','||'WEIGHTED_AVERAGE'||','||'TIME_CREATED' from dual; 
SELECT SMRY.SCORECARD_IDENTIFIER||','||SMRY.SCORECARD_NAME||','||INFO.SC_DESC||','||SMRY.SCORE_NAME||','||SMRY.TOTAL_ROWS||','||SMRY.INVALID_ROWS||','||
SMRY.SCORE||','||SMRY.METRIC_WEIGHT||','||SMRY.WEIGHTED_AVERAGE||','||SMRY.TIME_CREATED
Result
FROM 
SCORE_SMRY SMRY,
RX_SCORECARD_INFO INFO
WHERE
SMRY.SCORECARD_IDENTIFIER=INFO.SC_ID
spool off
exit;
```

Comment: it would be helpful if you give some sample data and expected out.

Comment: You haven't shown us your query, sample data, current output and what is wrong with it, and expected output. Are the 'some columns' in the middle of the query and others each side are OK; or are you losing data at the end of each line? We can't guess what you are doing wrong from what you've provided.

Comment: I am losing the data for the columns as well as next  columns data from where I encounter big length as well as multi line data like -- "Scorecard for ERI GTS table t_src_ins_gts represents below ERI Products -
GTS/Loans
GTS/LoC
GTS/Guarantees"

Comment: Please edit your question to show additional information - in particular, don't try to dump code into comments. (See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting))

Comment: @AlexPoole: yes i need some time to edit my query and put it here..thanks

Comment: @XING: I have uploaded a screenshot of the data in image description,there u can see that after third column,no data is coming as the third column has the data--  "Scorecard for ERI GTS table t_src_ins_gts represents below ERI Products - GTS/Loans GTS/LoC GTS/Guarantees"

Comment: Sorry to say that am not able to see image as not all the places images are visible. You can post it in simple text ,

Comment: would you consider using SQLCL instead of SQLPLUS where generating cvs format is handled natively with the "set sqlformat cvs" command?